# How do distribute space in a container div evenly between two divs with togglable visibility and varying content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a div container with 4 divs in it. 2 headers and 2 content divs. Clicking the headers will toggle the visibility of the content div below them.

There's 3 scenario's that I want to consider:

1. Both content divs are open (visible) and have overflow with scrolling. In this case I want them to both take up half of the available space.
2. 1 content div is open with or without overflow. In this case I want it to take up all the available space or the space that it needs.
3. Both content divs are closed. In this case I want the header divs to be on top of the container.

#### What's working

- If both divs have overflow and are open, the available space will be distributed equally.
- If one is closed the other one will fill in the available space. If both are closed only the headers will be displayed.

#### What's not working

- What happens when the bottom content div is closed and the top content div has overflow, is that the top content div will only grow to half the height of the container.
- When both content divs are open and have no overflow, they will grow to 50% of the height of the container and create empty space between the content div and the header div below it.

This is the structure of the HTML

```
<div class='flex-container'>
  <div id='header1' class='header'>
    Header 1
  </div>
  <div id='content1' class='header-content'>
    <div class='item'>Lorem</div>
    <div class='item'>Lorem</div>
    <div class='item'>Lorem</div>
    <div class='item'>Lorem</div>
    <div class='item'>Lorem</div>
    <div class='item'>Lorem</div>
    <div class='item'>Lorem</div>
    <div class='item'>Lorem</div>
    <div class='item'>Lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div id='header2' class='header'>
    Header 2
  </div>
  <div id='content2' class='header-content'>
    <div class='item'>Ipsum</div>
    <div class='item'>Ipsum</div>
    <div class='item'>Ipsum</div>
    <div class='item'>Ipsum</div>
    <div class='item'>Ipsum</div>
    <div class='item'>Ipsum</div>
    <div class='item'>Ipsum</div>
    <div class='item'>Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the styling I've applied in my attempt. It should be noted that I'm using Sass.

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 35px;
  background-color: #99e9f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-content {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 35px);
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .item {
    padding: 3px 12px;
    background-color: #e3fafc;
  }
}
```

[This](https://codepen.io/7EIIE/pen/mdabwZN) is a link to the codepen.

#### Things I've tried

- I've also tried using `max-heigth: calc(50% - 35px)` (the header is 35px long) which fixed the issue where the growing content div caused white space to appear, but it also made it so that the content div wouldn't grow above that if the other content div was closed.
- Using only `flex-grow: 1` without `flex-basis: calc(50% - 35px)` and `max-height: calc(50% - 35px)` did allow the content div to grow past ~50% of the container height but made the content divs uneven in height if one content div had more elements that the other, causing the available space to not be distributed equally.

Answer (score 1):

This accomplishes what you are trying to do. You can modify it as you see fit:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>Variable Percentage Height</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style>
        *,
        *::before
        *::after {
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: inherit;
            font-family: inherit;
            font-size: inherit;
            text-align: justify;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Lucida Grande', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Liberation Sans', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        #container {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .content {
            overflow: auto;
            background-color: #eec1ff;
            position: relative;
        }

        .content::after {
            position: absolute;
            inset: auto 0 0 0;
            display: block;
            z-index: 1;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #content1::after {
            content: 'this is the bottom of content div #1';
        }

        #content2::after {
            content: 'this is the bottom of content div #2';
        }

        .header {
            height: 35px;
            line-height: 35px;
            background-color: #99e9f2;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .item {
            padding: 3px 12px;
            background-color: #e3fafc;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="header" id="header1">Header 1</div>
    <div class="content" id="content1">
        <div class="item">Lorem</div>
        <div class="item">Lorem</div>
        <div class="item">Lorem</div>
        <div class="item">Lorem</div>
        <div class="item">Lorem</div>
        <div class="item">Lorem</div>
        <div class="item">Lorem</div>
        <div class="item">Lorem</div>
        <div class="item">Lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="header" id="header2">Header 2</div>
    <div class="content" id="content2">
        <div class="item">Ipsum</div>
        <div class="item">Ipsum</div>
        <div class="item">Ipsum</div>
        <div class="item">Ipsum</div>
        <div class="item">Ipsum</div>
        <div class="item">Ipsum</div>
        <div class="item">Ipsum</div>
        <div class="item">Ipsum</div>
        <div class="item">Ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        (() => {
            const header1 = document.getElementById("header1");
            const header2 = document.getElementById("header2");
            const content1 = document.getElementById("content1");
            const content2 = document.getElementById("content2");
            let header1open = false;
            let header2open = false;
            header1.onclick = updateHeights;
            header2.onclick = updateHeights;
            updateHeights(null);

            /**
             * @param {MouseEvent} e
             */
            function updateHeights(e) {
                const headerTotalHeight = header1.offsetHeight + header2.offsetHeight;
                if (e == null) {
                    content1.style.display = "none";
                    content2.style.display = "none";
                    header1open = false;
                    header2open = false;
                } else if (header1.contains(e.target)) {
                    if (header1open) {
                        header1open = false;
                        content1.style.display = "none";
                        if (header2open) {
                            content2.style.height = `calc(100% - ${headerTotalHeight}px)`;
                        }
                    } else {
                        header1open = true;
                        content1.style.removeProperty("display");
                        if (header2open) {
                            content1.style.height = `calc((100% - ${headerTotalHeight}px) / 2)`;
                            content2.style.height = `calc((100% - ${headerTotalHeight}px) / 2)`;
                        } else {
                            content1.style.height = `calc(100% - ${headerTotalHeight}px)`;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (header2.contains(e.target)) {
                    if (header2open) {
                        header2open = false;
                        content2.style.display = "none";
                        if (header1open) {
                            content1.style.height = `calc(100% - ${headerTotalHeight}px)`;
                        }
                    } else {
                        header2open = true;
                        content2.style.removeProperty("display");
                        if (header1open) {
                            content1.style.height = `calc((100% - ${headerTotalHeight}px) / 2)`;
                            content2.style.height = `calc((100% - ${headerTotalHeight}px) / 2)`;
                        } else {
                            content2.style.height = `calc(100% - ${headerTotalHeight}px)`;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })();
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was hoping it would have been possible with just css but I figured that might not be possible.

Comment: @Codekid flexboxes are often hit or miss...if my example helped you come to a solution please consider marking it as the answer

Comment: If you run the snippet in full screen and you open both content divs they are actually seperated by the pseudo elements you created. Maybe i didn't word it correctly but the reason i wanted to use flexbox was so that there was no empty space between the headers and content divs.

Comment: @Codekid there is no space between the headers and content divs in my example. I highlighted the content divs purple to demonstrate that. The pseudo elements are children of the content divs, and they fill up all available space.